# curving text inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
 $().ready(function() {
$('#demo1').circleType({fitText:true, radius: 180});   });
  $().ready(function() {
            $('#example').arctext({radius: 250});
        });
```

```css
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
```

```html
<div id="example">Here is curved text dmsdodsfnfsadknsdf></div>
<br>

<div id="demo1"> Here’s some curved text flowing clockwise.</div>
```

hello i was wondering if its possible to curve text inside a div using a button something like this [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: im just looking for the <script type CircleType.js> i was wondering if google is hosting or if i have to host it myself? sorry i didnt make myself clear i apologize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code shows that you're trying to use 2 different libraries: ArcText (http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/) and CircleType (http://circletype.labwire.ca/). You'll need to reference jQuery, ArcText, and Circletype libraries.

You should download both ArcText and Circletype to reference locally like this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/circletype.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
```

Then your JavaScript will run fine:

```
$(function(){
  $('#demo1').circleType( {fitText:true, radius: 180} );
  $('#example').arctext( {radius: 250} );
});
```

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/nyawqaab/